# Web page data extraction using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp

I would like to extract some specific information from web pages. Web pages contain person profiles, and I want to extract information such as name, email, research interested-areas. 
Structure of each page is different from one another. How can I extract such information using machine learning? What kind of a method, features I can use?

Or can I use NLP for such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, this seems to be a scraping problem which you can do using Beautifulsoup in python.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I have misunderstood the crawling and scraping.